# Excel: Clone cells and have the exact same value & formating

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Yesterday I tried to make another step with my network table to give an easy view on the current network cabling / patching of our company. I remember that I did something similar in the past but I think it was only the value that was mimiced.

Basically what I would like to do is that if I change the value of 
 `B145` on `Sheet1`, it should be updated in `B20` on `Sheet2`. Same goes with the formatting. If I change the color from nothing / white to red or dark grey or any other color it should as well change to that formatting. 
Sadly I did not find anything useful because it always gives me results for "just enter = in an empty field and select your target cell" or condition formatting.

Edit: As requested by Lee
[image]
On the left you can see the original table which will be updated whenever there is a change.
On the right you can see the cloned table which copies / clones the value but not the coloring.

Basically the S6.3 on the right should be red and if for example the entry on Slot 9 changes to empty or an important value, it should change the color to the same as the parent field.

For security reasons I cannot show more than this. Sorry.

Comment: Try to provide the sample about your problem, it's hard to help you with only letters description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use same value in different sheet just use formula ie in your case.
B20 cell in Sheet 2 would have formula 
`=Sheet1!$B$145`

for formatting it can't be done this way, AFAIK, but what you can do is make conditional formatting from the menu in a particular cell.
There you have options like
IF  Cell  value (=,>,<,'like'..) then use particular formatting to this cell (you can choose any formatting options as you do for any other cell in the spreadsheet).

Comment: Then it could be that there is no option to say, also copy the formatting. Do you know if it is possible to change the theme color without changing the borders at all? I am not very skilled with the conditional formatting but if that's possible it may come in very handy. Most formating I do is either, blank / empty for normal patches, Grey level 2 if "libre" (empty in french) or Red if it's S*., Sv*. or R1/2. for some of our important connections like switches, and servers.

Comment: @VarmintLP I'm not sure what you mean theme color.  Just use Conditional formatting is very easy and self explanatory.  For example I like to use for dates I use one cell ie A1 `=today()`.  Then I mark entire column of dates and choose conditional formatting if cell = A1 (modify background to ie green).  Similarly you can do for if cell empty ("") - double quotes.  background one way, <0 (negatives) boders red....  Try it it's fun.

Comment: Thx. Had a quick look and it is actually very straight forward. I will try to apply some condition formatting on my table, the next time I get some time to do so. Seems quite nifty and useful.

Comment: One way to copy format is to have macros running in the background waiting for a cell change in `Main rack (basic)` table, and then apply same change to `Main rack (More details)`.  But that requires coding which is not so straight forward if you haven't done it.